# My remix.eth page does not connect with my metamask account

Tags: metamask, testnets, rinkeby, remix-tests

When I choose the "injected web3" environment metamask does not automatically
pop-up,thus I have to manually connect my metamask account with the remix.eth web page.However when I do this the remix.eth page does not actually connect with the account (my metamask account does say "connected" but I dont see my account number in the remix.eth webpage). [image: Metamask won't popup automatically]

Answer (score 1):

First, try to disconnect your metamask from everything by clicking on that green "Connected" on the left side from metamask and then disconnect all accounts. After that lockout from Metamask and login again. and then refresh remix and try Injected Web3 again

Comment: Thx! that worked.